# <script> not returned in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, script-tag

I am creating a WordPress theme and using AJAX to load new archive pages. The problem is that the whole `< script type="text/javascript">//something//< /script>` is not returned in the newly-acquired content.

Suppose I have these codes initially :

```
<div id="post-1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //some codes here//
    </script>

    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

After navigating to the next page and back to this original page using AJAX, I will get these (in Firebug) instead :

```
<div id="post-1">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

The whole chunk of Javascript codes will not be returned, but under the 'Inline' script in 'Script' tab of Firebug, they are still there.

So, I'm wondering what have I done wrong in retrieving the new content using AJAX? Below is the code that I'm using :

```
    jQuery('.ajax-pagination a').live('click', function(e){ //check when pagination link is clicked and stop its action.
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href'); //Get the href attribute
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: link,
        dataType: "text",
        context: document.body,
        beforeSend: function(){jQuery('#container').fadeOut(500)},
        success: function(html) {
            var newhtml = $('#container', $(html))
            $('#container').html(newhtml);
            $("container").find("script").each(function(i) {
                eval($(this).text());
            });
            jQuery('#container').fadeIn(500);

        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
    });
```

I am trying to run the Javacript loaded via AJAX, but the problem seems to be that the Javascript itself isn't even returned together with the rest of the content.

Thanks for reading such a long question and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: whats the code that handles ajax request on the server side?

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'm sorry to say that I'm very new to AJAX and do not know which code handles it on the server side. I am using WordPress 3.4.2 and jQuery 1.6.1, if this information is useful.

Comment: In parts of your script you are using 'JQuery'. In other parts you are using the '$' alias, but I don't see anywhere that you've set up that '$' alias. WordPress loads jQuery in 'no conflict' mode, meaning that '$' is not set up automatically. Your problem may be something different than you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually I am just taking out part of the script and I already have this at the beginning of the .js file : $(document).ready(function($){

The thing which is still bugging me is that I don't know why everything, except all the Javascript codes, can be retrieved via AJAX. Normally people have the Javascript returned but not executed, but in my case, it is not returned at all. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The `.html()` method strips `<script>` tags from inserted HTML.

You'll need to traverse the HTML *before* you try to insert it to find all of the script tags and then use `jQuery.globalEval` to execute their contents.

```
success: function(html) {
    var newhtml = $('#container', $(html));

    // execute included script tags - assumes inline for now
    $('script', newhtml).each(function() {
        $.globalEval($(this).text());
    });

    $('#container').html(newhtml).fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: That's correct, as of jQ > 1.4... I did wrap my script into style type javascript tags ;)

Comment: Your edit won't work (as I remember) because $(html) does also intercept the script tags.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried it but the problem still remains there. I've even tried different dataType (such as "html") but still doesn't work.